# Variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$ that does not embed into flat scheme over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, derived-categories, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $X\to\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{F}_p$ be a smooth proper morphism. Is there a closed immersion $X\to Y$ where $Y$ is flat of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$?

As mentioned in the comments if $X$ is projective the problem is solved immediately. So a counterexample would have $\mathrm{dim}(X)\geq 3$.

Comment: For example, if $X$ is projective, you can take $\mathbf P^N_{\mathbf Z/p^2}$. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I think it is confusing that the answer to the question implicit in the title, and to the actual question in the body of the text, are opposite (whatever those answers are).  This is relevant because people often start an answer with "The answer is Yes", or whatever.

Comment: As a non-specialist my immediate response is, are there counterexamples to the stronger statements "X smooth implies there exist Y smooth" and "X flat implies there exist Y flat"?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie there were some similar questions (https://mathoverflow.net/q/410 https://mathoverflow.net/q/63969) but I don't know a counterexample to either of those two statements. It can also be noted that anything is flat over a field.